# Instagram Basic Display: Exchanging code for access_token works only after 5 minutes

Tags: node.js, facebook, instagram, access-token, instagram-api

Exchanging the code for an access_token works on our development server however on our production server there is a 5 minute delay until the code can be exchanged for an access token.

We are running Node.js and the timestamps on the production server are not out of sync.

The request on the server to exchange the code for an access_token returns an error

> Matching code was not found or was already used

However if I take the code and duplicate the request in Postman using the same app_id and app_secret it still fails the same way for the next 5 minutes.  After 5 minutes I successfully get an access_token.


As I mentioned before the code works properly in a development environment there is just this delay when running on our production server.

Comment: Found a solution.  This app was bundled onto an already approved Facebook app.  Creating a whole new app just for Instagram fixed the issue and the calls are returning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different factors when project going on production server:

- Make sure you have a working version of node and npm on the production server, the same version you have in development server.
- If you used npm modules and have a package.json file run npm i (optionally with --production)
- Run node the same as you did in development (e.g. node index.js)
- Make sure you are using same port as in development.

Also you can take reference from here [best-practice-of-node-js-in-production](https://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practice-of-node-js-in-production/)